# No sound from speakers

Tags: 11.04, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard

I was mucking with my sound card hardware profile in the Sound Preferences menu and I seem to have lost my sound. But what's strange is that when I open the Pulseaudio Volume Control panel I can see the audio bar moving and if I pause or stop my music, the bar stop. But no sound is coming out of my speakers.

And I've checked the obvious speaker connections, restarted the machine, `dpkg-reconfigure pulseaudio`, deleted the .pulse folder from my home directory, etc. Nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

The soundcard is an internal CL Sound Blaster, the onboard audio is turned off on my motherboard.

Comment: Solved the problem. I have a webcam with microphone that was grabbing top stop in `/proc/asound/modules`

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. I have a webcam with microphone that was grabbing top stop in `/proc/asound/modules`

Answer (score 0):

First check your card hwC0D0 or hwC1D0: In my laptop hwC0D0 is for intel hdmi and hwC1D0 is for realtek alc663. You can know it with hdajackretask first is hwC0D0.

Install hdajackretask and hda-jack-sense-test(hdajacksensetest in opensuse). First unplug subwoofer and run code below (-c 1 for hwC1D0)

hdajacksensetest -a -s -c 1

Then attach and rerun. You will find correct pin Then assign speakerto pin with hdajackretask.