# Sound from Headphones, though no sound from speakers [HP Spectre X360 EB0053DX] [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, speakers

as the title says my speakers don't have any sound.

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and linux in general. I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 into my 2020 HP Spectre x360 EB0053DX and have been testing features to find out what works and what might have issues. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is with my speakers.

I have confirmed that the sound bar within the sound settings is working, I'm just not receiving any sound. I have tried the following:

1. Tested playing with pavucontrol
2. Tested playing with alsamixer - verified auto mute is disabled and mute functionality of laptop buttons.
3. Reinstalling Pulse audio, pavucontrol, alsamixer
4. Editing alsa-base.conf to add model=generic
5. Tested headphone jack - works

[No sound from speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51801/no-sound-from-speakers)

I do feel like this might play a role in the issue but not sure how to interpret it other than trying to identify a specific source using top within the terminal. I'm not sure what I'm looking for other than the topline within the configuration file of modules.

I've searched and seems like everything that has potential, fails to resolve my issue and I'm hoping someone out there can help me out.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: How are your speakers hooked up to the computer? Is it the rather standard jack in the back or is it through HDMI? Also, back in pavucontrol, make sure you check what's going on in the drop-down menu in the output tab.

Comment: Hey, my speakers are integrated as it is a laptop.

Comment: Hmm... That's bizarre. Does your laptop have an Fn key combo that mutes the internal speakers?

Comment: Yes, I verified functionality and auto mute being disabled and all that jazz when testing alsamixer.

Comment: Alright, I'd [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265780/edit) your question to add those last bits of info (maybe even including laptop model) - so that more folks see it. I'm unsure of the cause.

Comment: The laptop model is in the subject. I’ll elaborate on my testing with alsamixer. Thanks !

Comment: I just did a bit of searching. In your edit, could you also add which version of Ubuntu you're using?

Comment: Have you checked Settings -> Sound and then what options are given for Output Device? When I upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 20.04 this had unexpectedly changed.

Comment: On my older HP Spectre 360, the laptop speakers work fine. In Settings -> Sound, I have "Output Device" = "Speakers - Built-in Audio". As Joe suggested, see what value your system has.